# contiki compression library implemention

Tags: compression, contiki

I am working with telosB sensors in instant contiki-2.7 OS. So far I have implemented aggregation of strings (sending temperature ,light,humidity) in the intermediate node before forwarding to sink in a network,using rimestack . But now I wanted to implement compression of strings using SBZIP in rimestack.

I have downloaded the source codes , but not been able to implement the library and functions to compress my string. If somebody has anyexperience in using any compression libraries in contiki, feel free to comment here.
Thanks in advance
Salekin Imran

Comment: Hi Salekin. Please describe what problems you're having and create a MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have included the necessary header files, and all the auxiliary files are in the same folder. but when I'm trying to call a function: C-S-T-A.co: In function `sbz_compress': C-S-T-A.c:(.text.sbz_compress+0x1c): undefined reference to `sbz_rle_e'
C-S-T-A.c:(.text.sbz_compress+0x32): undefined reference to `sbz_bwt_e'
C-S-T-A.c:(.text.sbz_compress+0x44): undefined reference to `sbz_mtf_e'
C-S-T-A.c:(.text.sbz_compress+0x52): undefined reference to `sbz_ahc_e'

C-S-T-A.c:(.init9+0x10): undefined reference to `fprintf'
C-S-T-A.c:(.init9+0x74): undefined reference to `fputs'

Comment: How are you linking with the library? Please update the question. `fprintf` and `fputs` are not available in Contiki, if the library requires them it's not going to work.